# Relatively Simple But I Don't Know What To Do.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can anyone help me solve
$$
 2\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  & 0^{n\times n} 
    \\
    0^{n\times n}   & I^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix} \ddot{\sigma}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
    0^{n\times n} & \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  
    \\
    -\frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}   & 0^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix}\dot{\sigma}(t)
$$

with initial conditions $\sigma(0)=\begin{pmatrix} q \\ p \end{pmatrix},$ $\sigma(1)=\begin{pmatrix} q' \\ p' \end{pmatrix}$. Here $h>0$, I really don't know how to go about it. With $p,q,q',p'\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Are $p,p',q,q'$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Hint: If $\sigma = (Q_1,\ldots,Q_n,P_1,\ldots,P_n)^T$, $(P_k,Q_k)$ for different $k$ decouples.
$$2
\begin{bmatrix}\frac1h & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \ddot{Q}_k \\ \ddot{P}_k \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &\frac1h \\ -\frac1h & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{Q}_k \\ \dot{P}_k \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes :)

Comment: The "usual" approach would be to make this a higher dimension first order system. First, solve this for $\ddot \sigma$:
$$
 2\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  & 0^{n\times n} 
    \\
    0^{n\times n}   & I^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix} \ddot{\sigma}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
    0^{n\times n} & \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  
    \\
    -\frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}   & 0^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix}\dot{\sigma}(t) \implies
$$

Comment: $$
 \ddot{\sigma}(t)=
\frac 12
\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  & 0^{n\times n} 
    \\
    0^{n\times n}   & I^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
    0^{n\times n} & \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  
    \\
    -\frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}   & 0^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix}\dot{\sigma}(t)
\\ = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    0^{n\times n} & \frac{1}{2}I^{n\times n}  
    \\
    -\frac{1}{2h}I^{n\times n}   & 0^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix} \dot \sigma(t).
$$

Comment: Let $A$ denote this coefficient matrix so that $\ddot \sigma(t) = A\dot \sigma(t)$. We can rewrite this has a higher dimensional first order system by defining the variable
$$
\tau(t) = \pmatrix{\sigma(t)\\ \dot \sigma(t)}.
$$
We can rewrite your system as 
$$
\frac d{dt} \pmatrix{\sigma(t)\\ \dot \sigma(t)} = \pmatrix{0 & I_{(2n) \times (2n)}\\0 & A} \pmatrix{\sigma(t)\\ \dot \sigma(t)}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement the other answer: you will end up with a general solution of the form
$$
\sigma(t) = e^{At}D + C
$$
for undetermined vectors $C,D \in \Bbb R^{2n}$. Plugging in initial conditions yields
$$
\sigma(0) = e^{A\cdot 0}D + C = D + C, \\
\sigma(1) = e^{A \cdot 1}D + 1 \cdot C  = e^A D + C.
$$
Solve this to get $D = (e^A - I)^{-1}(\sigma(1) - \sigma(0))$ and $C = \sigma(0) - D$.

Note that $e^A - I$ is invertible in most cases.

---

Consider the case where $e^A - I$ fails to be invertible. This means that $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $e^\lambda = 1$. Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm \frac 1{2 \sqrt{h}} i$, this occurs if and only if there is an integer $k$ for which
$$
\frac 1{2 \sqrt{h}} = 2 \pi k \implies h = \frac 1{(4\pi k)^2}.
$$
In this case, we find that
$$
e^{tA} = \cos(2 \pi k t) I + 2 \sqrt{h}\sin(2 \pi k t)A.
$$
This means that any solution $\sigma(t) = e^{At}D + C$ **is periodic with period 1**.  It follows that the initial conditions of $\sigma(0)$ and $\sigma(1)$ are not sufficient to find $\sigma(t)$, and there can only be such a solution if $\sigma(0) = \sigma(1)$.

Comment: With the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}  0 & \frac{1}{2}I^{n\times n} \\ \frac{1}{2h}I^{n\times n}  & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is $e^A$ easily computable in closed form? It seems hard since it is not diagonal

Comment: @Flows Don't forget about the sign on the bottom left entry! In fact, there's a nice trick here: as a consequence of the fact that $A^2 + \frac 1{4h} I_{(2n)\times(2n)} = 0$, we can conclude that
$$
e^{tA} = \cos\left( \frac{t}{2\sqrt{h}}\right) I + \sin\left( \frac{t}{2\sqrt{h}}\right) A.
$$

Comment: Isnt $A^2=-\frac{1}{4h}I_{2n\times 2n}$

Comment: Nice trick though!!! :), let me try and see what you have done!

Comment: @Flows. Yes. That is equivalent to what I wrote if you move the $I$ to the left side

Comment: oops read it wrong haha!

Comment: Should it be $2\sqrt{h}\sin(\frac{t}{2\sqrt{h}})A$?  when you write out the $\sin$ series need to multiply and divide by an extra $2\sqrt{h}$ to get the power right?

Comment: @Flows That's correct! Bit of a mistake there on my part

Comment: Don't be silly you have been incredibly helpful! How come the solution in matrix form is written differently here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Solution_in_matrix_form ? i.e without this linear dependence on $t$ like you have?

Comment: @Flows Keep in mind that (per the other answer's recommendation of integrating as a first step), we were considering the *inhomogeneous* system of ODE's
$$
\dot \sigma - A \sigma = C
$$
for some matrix $A$ and vector $C$

Comment: True but writing $ \dot{\sigma}-A\sigma=C$ as $\dot{\sigma}=A(\sigma+A^{-1}C) $ it is in that form. Anywho if we have $\sigma=e^{tA}D+tC$ using the initial conditions $\sigma(0)=(q,p),\sigma(1)=(q',p')$ to find $D$ and $C$ it seems strange that the second derivative of $\sigma$ i.e $\ddot{\sigma}$ does not depend on $\sigma(1)$.

Comment: @Flows You're right, I made another mistake there. See my latest edit.

Comment: Where do you find the statement $e^{A}-I$ is invertible IFF $A$ is? Since I can pick $h$ such that $A =I $ namely $h=\frac{1}{16k^2\pi^2}$

Comment: @Flows Good catch... again. The correct statement is that $e^{tA} - I$ is invertible for all $t$ iff $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Forgetting the for all $t$. $A$ (lets call it $A_h$ since it depends on $h$) is invertible for any $h$, but I can choose $h$ such that $e^{A_h}=I$ and hence $e^{A_h}-I$ is not invertible. hmm sorry for all these messages I just came back to this after some hours of needed rest.

Comment: @Flows. No problem. So what it comes down to is that if $h$ is such that $e^{A_h} - I$ fails to be invertible, then we have a different general solution.

Comment: Very interesting thank you :) I am surprised $e^{A}-I$ is invertible IFF $A$ is invertible. I can see that $A$ invertible  $\implies$ $e^A$ invertible but I don't know the conditions to ensure taking away the identity retains the invertibility. Infact yeh this IFF cannot hold by what I said earlier.

Comment: Right so IFF does not hold. In our case, it is notable that $e^A - I$ can only fail to be invertible when $e^A = I$.

Comment: @Flows See my latest edit. The general solution does not change. What does change is that there might not be a solution that fits the initial conditions, and the initial conditions are insufficient to determine the full trajectory $\sigma(t)$.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, if only I could upvote again!

Comment: Infact I think for many choices of $h$ $e^{A_h}-I$ is not invertible. Making $\sin =-1$ $\cos =0$ for instance.

Comment: @Flows in this case $e^A - I$ has the form $c \cdot A - I$, and is necessarily invertible. Note that $(c \cdot A - I)(c \cdot A + I)$ is a non-zero multiple of the identity matrix

Comment: It has the form $e^A-I=-2\sqrt{h}A -I$ but  $$-\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sqrt{h} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ is not invertible :( i.e zero determinant.

Comment: @Flows You have a mistake somewhere, the off-diagonal entries should have opposite signs

Comment: oh my god your right... i was copying from my earlier comment !

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$
 A:=2\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  & 0^{n\times n} 
    \\
    0^{n\times n}   & I^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix},\quad B:=\begin{pmatrix}
    0^{n\times n} & \frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}  
    \\
    -\frac{1}{h}I^{n\times n}   & 0^{n\times n} 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Integrate both sides over $t$, you get

$$
A\dot{\sigma}(t)=B\sigma(t)+C
$$

for some $C\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Thus

$$
\dot{\sigma}(t)=A^{-1}B\sigma(t)+C'
$$

for some other $C'\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Now the [usual solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) for linear systems kicks in.